# Mobile Device.dll produces "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'" when using iPhone.GetFileInfo()

Tags: c#, ios, iphone

I am trying to get information about my iPhone's filesystem. Namely, a file on the iphone. I can generate the listing of files that exist on the phone and even search for files, but for some reason I cannot generate information or the content about the file.

Here is the code I am using within my iPhone.cs class file:

```
    using MobileDevice;

    public void Data()
    {

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in iPhone.GetFileInfo("/notify.conf"))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(entry.Value, entry.Key);
        }
    }
```

Here is how the function is defined within the given library:

public System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary GetFileInfo(string path)
    Member of MobileDevice.iPhone

Comment: Well presumably `GetFileInfo` is an instance method, so you need an instance of the unconventionally-named `iPhone` class. Look at the related questions on the right...

Comment: Doh, I just realized I was creating an instance of the class already in previous code. All I had to do was use that reference instead of the MobileDevice reference. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean it's unconventionally-named?

Comment: It doesn't follow normal C# naming conventions, where classes are PascalCased.